# How to handle HTTP response with a 4xx/5xx status code, Java servlet/HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, servlets, httpurlconnection, http-status-codes, sitebricks

In my Java servlet, there are instances where I want to return an HTTP status code signifying an error and I want the client to be able to read and handle the response based on the status code returned. For example, my application deals with the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) for the Google App Engine Java runtime. If the requesting client ID has not yet requested a token for the channel, then the servlet will return a *403* status code and the client will handle the response accordingly (request a token immediately from the servlet).

However, when the client reads the HTTP response using *HttpURLConnection*. Instead of being able to read the response from the input stream, I am thrown this lovely stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8083/rest/fb/echo
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1458)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1452)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1106)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8083/rest/fb/echo
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1403)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:397)
```

While I was writing this post, I began to think that perhaps I should not read from the connection's input stream if I read a status code from the connection that signified a non-success. Regardless, I'd love to hear what others think about this.

#### NOTE

My servlet uses [Sitebricks](http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/) to provide my methods with a REST endpoint to listen to. Also, Sitebricks allows me to send the response and status code like so:

```
MyObject response = ...;
int statusCode = ...;
...
return Reply.with(response).as(Json.class).type("application/json").status(statusCode);
```

Comment: What happens if you catch that IOException and ignore it? Ah, oh wait... you check the return-code before reading from input stream, right?

Comment: Ya I'm realizing that checking status code before reading from input stream is the right way to go.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While I was writing this post, I began to think that perhaps I should
>   not read from the connection's input stream if I read a status code
>   from the connection that signified a non-success. Regardless, I'd love
>   to hear what others think about this.

I do think you're right. You'll have to check status before reading from input stream.